How many fighters and how much material from the US-trained Palestinian security forces have passed to Hamas?
How many fighters and ho much material from the US-trained Palestinian security forces have passed to Hamas (or other Islamist militias)?
Since signing the Oslo accords the US have tried to train Palestinian security forces, investing about a billion dollars in them. The part of this forces in Gaza has desintegrated after the Hamas takeover in 2007:

With U.S. encouragement, Palestinian officials have dusted off lists of their old security forces in Gaza, 17 years after Hamas violently ousted the authority from the enclave. Out of 26,000 names, only 2,000 to 3,000 are thought capable of becoming fit for duty.

I wonder how many of the US-trained officers have joined Hamas and other Islamist movements, and how much material was passed. I am also interested, if there was significant leakage from the PA security to Islamists in the West Bank.
Background: United States security assistance to the Palestinian National Authority

One can probably find out how much of the US money actually went into material and what kind of material. But for the personal you would need a named list both for the people trained back than and for current Hamas fighters, neither of which will be available publically (if they exist as all).

Minor gripe: your source says "more than a billion dollars in foreign funding", not necessarily from the US, although I suspect the US provided most of it. Various European countries have also trained the Palestinian police IIRC.

The US mostly trained Fatah personnel, most of them were either executed or expelled from Gaza during the Hamas takeover. Their equipment might have been left behind, but is probably long destroyed or is past its useful life even if not.
